# How to use two jQuery UI Autocomplete Widgets on one input element?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

Hi everybody I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget, which looks like this

```
/* autocomplete for city input */
$(function(){

$("#input_element").autocomplete({
source:"fetch_city_query.php",
minLength: 2
});
});

/* autocomplete for zip input */
$(function(){

$("#input_element").autocomplete({
source:"fetch_zip_query.php",
minLength: 2
});});
```

Basically I have an input element where I want the user to either input a zip code or a city name, and depending on the input, if it is numeric, then I would like to call the auto complete for the zip input and if its non numeric then I want to call the city autocomplete. How can I go about screening the input and calling the respective autocomplete?

Comment: Would be easier to do that detection in the php page and return in both case the same result format so you stick to one autocomplete instance for the input, no ?

Comment: YEs you are correct. I ended up solving the problem by implementing a solution through the php proccess.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be attaching two autocomplete elements, instead you should be using the events to switch your source.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Have a look at the 'search' or 'change' events and try switching the source.

Note - Ideally though, I would recommend that you point to one source and just have the server handle the response depending on the input.